# getView Method of Listview call multiple time

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, getview

**getView method** in Adapter of list view call multiple time at postion 0
So it is Taking a more time to Load this Activity 
 and also set Bitamp Every time in Imageview when getView called

i also try to set list view height as fillparent but not solve my problem

**ListView in Xml File**

```
      <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
       <ListView  android:id="@+id/lv_order_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
                    </ListView> 
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**getView method in Listview**

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            myView = convertView;
            System.out.println("get view" + position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            myView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            ImageView img_order = (ImageView) myView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_order);
            TextView title_of_ink = (TextView) myView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_of_ink);
             title_of_ink.setText("Text");
            picasso.load("url").noFade().into(img_order);
            return myView;
        }
```

Comment: you did not state your problem..
Also it is very known that android calls getView on position 0 multiple times. I'm not sure if its a bug or a feature, but its a system thing.

Comment: Who is the parent of your listview ? is it linear, relative, frame layout?

Comment: Relative Layout is parent of listview

Answer (score 3):

`getView` will be called multiple times during scrolling, it's how `ListView` works.

In order to improve performance there are two techniques you can use:
1) View recycling - which you are doing WRONG

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Position " + position);

    return convertView;
}
```

2) Use the ViewHolder pattern

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText("Position " + position);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
}
```

3) Async loading of images
it's with capital P and you are missing the `Context` argument

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Code borrowed from [lucasr.org](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/).